# What to return from a method if certain conditions haven't been met?

Tags: c++, oop, exception, matrix

I'm writing a Matrice class (for practice sake) and when I wrote the method to multiply two Matrice objects I had to check if certain conditions are met for matrix multiplication:

```
Matrix Matrix::mul(const Matrix &mat)
{
    if(col != mat.row)
        //we cannot multiply in this case
    else
    {
        //create temp object result
        //perform multiplication
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Now I'm curious on what to do if the condition hasn't been met because back in main.cpp I'd write something like this:

```
Matrix a = b.mul(c);
```

Now what if b and c cannot be multiplied, what should I return?
Is the best way to throw an exception, to just force the person using that class to send compatible matrices, is there another better way?

Comment: return `std::optional`, or throw.

Comment: If your matrices are of fixed size (and compile time constants), you can move the sizes into template parameters. Then (assuming you got the signature right), the compiler won't let you multiply matrices of wrong sizes :)

Comment: They are dynamically created, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return anything, throw an [exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) instead:

```
if (failure)
    throw std::runtime_error("Exception!!");
```

You can throw any of the [different exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) that suits your case more.

By the way, you could take a look at my project called *Matrix* [on GitHub](https://github.com/ForceBru/Matrix) for an example of how one could create such a class to operate on matrices.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with preconditions you can

- Throw an exception.
- Return a C++17 `std::optional`, or `boost::optional`.
- Call `std::terminate`.

Broken preconditions usually mean that the logic in the calling code is erroneous. One common approach is therefore to just `assert` the preconditions and test extensively. Ideally that will ensure that the preconditions are never broken.

To help the calling code, it can be a good idea to provide it with at least one way to check whether the call *would* fail.

Answer (score 1):

**What are the possible approaches ?**

1. return some neutral value that shows there is a problem (e.g. an empty matrix)
2. handle the error, but only while debugging: e.g. use `assert()` to verifiy and document pre- and post-conditions as well as invariants.
3. throw an exception to notify that there's a problem: let the caller  (or the caller of the caller) decide what to do.  If the exception isn't catch , the code will abort.  The nice thing is that you can provide additional error information.

**Which one should you choose ?**

Solution (1) should be used if the error situation is frequent (almost normal) and the function is called often.  I wouldn't advise you to use it here.

Solution (2) could be used if the error condition is not expected to happen, and you have confidence that the error situation is prevented (e.g. the user interface would prevent such errors to happen).

Solution (3) is for when the error situation is not really expected and could not really be prevented.  According to me, this should be a good candidate solution for your matrix multiplication.

**Example for solution 3**:

Instead of using a general purpose [exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/) or creating your own specific one, you could use [`domain_error`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/domain_error/) (domain in the mathematical sense, i.e. the argument is a valid value, but the function is not defined for that value)  or [`invalid_argument`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/invalid_argument/):

```
// in your multiplication 
...
if(col != mat.row)
    throw std::invalid_argument ("Matrix multiplication operand of incompatible size"); 
...

// In the calling program: 
...
try {
    a = b.mul(c);   
} 
catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    cout << "Invalid argument provided: " << e.what()<<endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what should I return?

It depends on your requirements.

> Is the best way to throw an exception

It could be. That depends on your requirements.

---

You have a few options:

1. Terminate the process. A developer can analyse the core dump to figure out what happened. The advantage of this is that a bug is hard to miss.
2. Don't even test preconditions within the function. Simply state the preconditions. If the caller violates the preconditions, the behaviour is undefined. This is the most efficient solution but relies on the user of the function to use it correctly.
3. Test the condition with `assert`. If the test fails, the process is terminated. Assertions are disabled with `NDEBUG` macro, so you can disable the check for optimal performance. This allows picking 1. or 2. depending on debug vs release build so is more flexible than either.
4. Throw an exception. This allows the caller to ignore the possibility of a failure if it cannot be handled, and let code higher in the call stack deal with it... or let the process terminate if it cannot be handled.
5. Return `std::optional`. This allows the caller to check if there is a return value and decide which of 1...4 option they wish to use to handle a missing one. If the caller ignores the possibility of non-existing return value, then it defaults to 2. (undefined behaviour).